Make StatTransfer Preserve Output Filename Case
I have been using R to write a StatTransfer .stcmd file that converts a dataset I've output as .csv, .dta, and .sav to .sas7bdat since R's output functions were producing errors with the set when outputting to SAS. The .dta file is used for this transfer which is run from an executable .cmd file that calls the .stcmd file.
My Problem:
The output file does not preserve the filename's case. e.g. yyyymmdd_FILE_Name.dta -> yyyymmdd_file_name.sas7bdat.
However, it does preserve cases transferring to a .sas file.
Searching the StatTransfer documentation, I have only been able to find reference to preserving variable names' cases, not filenames.
My .stcmd file is similar to:
COPY "C:\directory\FILE_DataSet_yyyymmdd.dta" "C:\directory\FILE_DataSet_yyyymmdd.sas7bdat" -y
COPY "C:\directory\FILE_DataSet_yyyymmdd.dta" "C:\directory\FILE_DataSet_yyyymmdd.sas" -y
QUIT

And produces:
file_dataset_yyyymmdd.sas7bdat
FILE_DataSet_yyyymmdd.sas

But the .sas7bdat and .sas file names should be the same.

Is there an operator I am missing that would preserve this?
Do sas7bdat files have filename requirements I am not aware of that StatTransfer is working around? (e.g. in the past I have had to limit filename's lengths. These files' actual names are 24 characters long.)
I seem to recall this not being a problem for me in the past, is this possibly due to version changes? (I am running what appears to be version 13.3.984.0312 on a Windows 11 machine)

I'm unable to specify this as a StatTransfer question since this doesn't appear to be a popular program on stackoverflow
